# magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: No method named "openModal"

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, magento-2.3

I am using magento 2.3 version. I make a custom module. In the custom module, I need 2 popups (using bootstrap modal).

Here is my js code -

JS code:

```
define(


    [

        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie',
    ],


    function ($, Component) {

        'use strict';

        var mageJsComponent = function (data) {
            var getData = JSON.stringify(data);
            var jsongetData = JSON.parse(getData);
            var height_value = jsongetData["height"];
            var width_value = jsongetData["width"];
            var coockie_value = jsongetData["coockieexpire"];
            var coockie_value = coockie_value*3600;
            $(document).ready(
                function ($) {
                console.log("ageverification.phtml : document loaded");
                });
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                // buttons: [{}],
                modalClass: 'custom_age_verfication',
                responsiveClass: 'ageverification-poup'
            };
            $(document).keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).mousedown(function (e) {
                    return true;
                });

                if ($.cookie('status') != 1) {
                    var ageconf = document.getElementsByClassName('ageconf');
                    if (ageconf.length > 0) {
                        if (document.getElementById("popup").classList.contains('ageconf')) {
                            $(document).mousedown(function (e) {
                                return false;
                            });
                        }
                    }


                   var mdl = jQuery('.age-pop-up').modal(options);
                    jQuery('.age-pop-up').modal('openModal');
                    // Click on enter button
                    $('#enter').click(function () {
                        if (coockie_value == "") {
                            coockie_value = 1;
                        }
                        $.cookie('status', '1', {
                            expires: +coockie_value
                        });
                        jQuery('.age-pop-up').modal('closeModal');
                        window.location.reload();
                        // detect safari browser
                        if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });

                    $('#no').click(function () {
                        if (coockie_value == "") {
                            coockie_value = 1;
                        }
                        $.cookie('status', '0', {
                            expires: +coockie_value
                        });
                        var mdl = jQuery('.not-verify').modal();
                        jQuery('.not-verify').modal('openModal');
                        jQuery('.age-pop-up').modal('closeModal');
                        jQuery('.age-pop-up.not-verify').show();
                    });
                }
            });
            // end : pop-up  age verification content
        };
        return mageJsComponent;
    });
```

phtml file:

```
<div class="outer-bg">
    <div id="popup" class="pop-cont age-pop-up ageconf">
        <div class="verify">
            <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($popupblockid)->toHtml(); ?>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <a id="enter" class="button valid-age" title="<?php echo $agreebtn; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $agreebtn; ?></a>
                    <h4>Or</h4>
                    <a id="no" class="button not-valid-age" title="<?php echo $disagreebtn; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $disagreebtn; ?></a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup1" class="not-verify age-pop-up">
        <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($disagreepopupblockid)->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the console, I am getting this error when I refresh page third time:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: No method named "openModal"
>     at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.bundle.js:4795)
>     at Function.each (jquery.js:370)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
>     at jQuery.fn.init._jQueryInterface [as modal] (bootstrap.bundle.js:4783)
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (ageverification.js:69)
>     at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>     at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
>     at mageJsComponent (ageverification.js:38)
>     at main.js:31
> ```

I am showing 1 modal at the time of refresh, in the popup, there is 2 button one is for confirm and second is for the exit, if click on confirm button then it should be redirected to the home page or if click on exit then shows the second popup.

Comment: Possibly  related https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294054/magento-2-no-method-named-openmodal-when-bootstrap-bundle-js-is-used

Comment: Had you found any possible solution? Editing etc/view.xml doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho No i tried with 1 popup then error goes